# Move first div below second div via CSS only

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have 2 divs inside a container like this:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="first">Hello World</div>
   <div id="second">I want to be at the top</div>
</div>
```

I want to align the first div below the second div without changing the HTML. How is this possible?

Here is my CSS:

```
#container {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}

#first {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
}

#second {
    float:left;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
}
```

I am aware I can set `position:fixed` to `#second` and align it to the top but is there any other way to achieve this?

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pcc1by9/).

The height of the divs are depending on the content inside. The fixed height above is only for testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the heights of the div's, you can use margin-top to solve this problem.

```
#container {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}

#first {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:lightblue;
    height:200px;
    margin-top: 200px;
}

#second {
    float:left;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    background:yellow;
    margin-top: -400px;
}
```

If you do not know the heights, you can use flexbox with the order property.

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#first {
    order: 2;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:lightblue;
}

#second {
    order: 1;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:yellow;
}
```

As lyjackal mentioned in another answer, you can also use `column-reverse` instead of `column`, which reverses the elements. Choose what suits you the best.

Comment: Unfortunately, the height was set only as a demonstration. The height is depending on the content.

Comment: Right, I added a solution that makes use of flexbox, which works also if you do not know the heights.

Comment: Note that browser support for flexbox is not great, see http://caniuse.com/#search=flex If you need IE8 support, you cannot use flexbox.

Comment: Fuq Internet Explorer ;)

Answer (score 2):

you can use flex-box and reverse the column

```
#container {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x3bmtd2t/)

Answer (score 0):

all can, but this is fixed height so modify you css

```
#container {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}

#first {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    margin-top:200px;
}

#second {
    float:left;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:-400px;
}
```